# Intersection of subfields is isomorphic to $Frac(R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $R\subseteq F$ a subdomain of $F$. We consider $K$ the intersection of all subfields of $F$ that contain $R$. I want to prove that $K\cong Frac(R)$.

I tried this:

$$\phi:Frac(R)\to K,\phi\left(\dfrac ab\right)=ab^{-1}.$$

This is homomorphism because:

$$\phi\left(\dfrac ab\cdot\dfrac cd\right)=(ac)(bd)^{-1}=...=\phi\left(\dfrac ab\right)\phi\left(\dfrac cd\right)$$

The same for sum, and $\phi(1/1)=1$, etc.

But I really don't see if $\phi$ is injective or surjective. Maybe I'm wrong.

What do you think?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to start by proving that $\phi$ is *well defined*, if you define $Frac(R)$ as a set of equivalence classes.

$\phi$ is injective because its domain is a field. (What can $\ker \phi$ be?)

$\phi$ is surjective because the image of $\phi$ is a field containing $R$. (How is this field related to $K$ ?)

Comment: I see. $K\subseteq \phi(Frac(R))$ because the definition of $K$, and $K\subseteq \phi(Frac(R))$ because $\phi$ is a function. Thank you @lhf